# Absolute value of Bose-Einstein distribution

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I would like to produce a 3D plot of `|n_B(z)| = (e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(y) + 1)^(-1/2)`, where `|n_B(z)|` is the absolute value of the Bose-Einstein distribution `n_B(z) = 1/(e^(z/T) - 1)` of the complex variable `z = x + i y`. (I set the temperature `T = 1` for simplicity.) Here's what I have so far.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$\Re(p_0)$,
        ylabel=$\Im(p_0)$,
        zlabel=$n_B(p_0)$,
        restrict z to domain*=0:2,
        tickwidth=0pt
    ]

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-10:-5,y domain=-30:30,
        blue!20,samples=5]
        {1};

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-5:5,y domain=-30:30,
        blue!20,samples=70]
        {(e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(deg(y)) + 1)^(-1/2)};

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=5:10,y domain=-30:30,
        blue!20,samples=5]
        {0};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I increased the sample rate close to TeX's maximum capacity and tried to concentrate that sampling on the region where it actually matters by approximating the function as 0 for `x >> 0` and 1 for `x << 0` where it is almost constant. However, the plot still shows small artifacts around the singularities. Any suggestions on how to improve the appearance and compilation speed would be welcome!

Comment: The "overshooting" can be prevented by adding `miter limit=1` to the `axis` environment options.

Comment: Using `y domain=-10:10` should be adequate to show the cyclical nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun:

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$\Re(p_0)$,
        ylabel=$\Im(p_0)$,
        zlabel=$n_B(p_0)$,
        miter limit=1,
        tickwidth=0pt
    ]

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-10:10,y domain=-10:10,
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.2,
        blue!20,samples=20,samples y=25]
        {(e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(deg(y)) + 1)^(-1/2)};

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-2:1,y domain=-10:10,
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.5,
        blue!20,samples=20,samples y=50]
        {(e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(deg(y)) + 1)^(-1/2)};

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-1:0.5,y domain=5.3:7.3,
        restrict z to domain*=0:2,
        blue!20,samples=20,samples y=20]
        {(e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(deg(y)) + 1)^(-1/2)};

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-1:0.5,y domain=-1:1,
        restrict z to domain*=0:2,
        blue!20,samples=20,samples y=20]
        {(e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(deg(y)) + 1)^(-1/2)};

    \addplot3[
        surf,domain=-1:0.5,y domain=-7.3:-5.3,
        restrict z to domain*=0:2,
        blue!20,samples=20,samples y=20]
        {(e^(2*x) - 2*e^x*cos(deg(y)) + 1)^(-1/2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```